# Fibonacci series in python giving odd results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have started learning python and my first program on fibonacci started giving me some weird answer, I know I am missing conceptually something so need guide from some expert on this. My program looks like this

```
#! usr/bin/python
a,b = 0, 1
while (b < 50):
    print(b)
    a = b
    b = a + b
```

**output**

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
```

But When i wrote like this I got correct result

```
#! usr/bin/python
a,b = 0, 1
while (b < 50):
    print(b)
    a,b = b, a + b
```

**output:**

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

Guide me pls

Comment: In the top code, you set a=b, then b=a +b.  So you really have a=b and b=b+b.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a,b = 0,1
a = b          # a <- 1
b = a + b      # b <- a + b (1 + 1 = 2)
```

That's two *separate* operations where the `a` in the final line has already been modified before use.

On the other hand:

```
a,b = b, a + b
```

is an *atomic* operation where everything on the right side of `=` is the *original* value.

Hence it's equivalent to:

```
a,b = 0,1
t = a          # t <- 0
a = b          # a <- 1
b = t + b      # b <- t + b (0 + 1 = 1)
```